# divisor of inverse image sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $S$ be a surface given by $S:= \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and we have the canonical morphism $pr_i: S \to \mathbb{P}^1$ for $i = 1,2$.

Define the invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}:= pr_1 ^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1))$ on $S$.

Let $a \in \mathbb{P}^1$ be a closed point, such that $pr_i^{-1}(a) \cong \mathbb{P}^1$.

My question is: How to see that the divisor $\{ a \} \times \mathbb{P}^1 \cong \mathbb{P}^1$ corresponds to $\mathcal{L}$?
Or in other words, why in the exact sequence

$ 0 \to \mathcal{L}^{\vee} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2} \to \mathcal{O}_D \to 0$

$D$ coincides with $\mathbb{P}^1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathbb P^1=\mathbb PV$, where $V$ is a two-dimensional vector space with coordinate functions $x_1,x_2$. The sheaf $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1)$ has a rational (in fact, global) section, corresponding to $x_1$. Then the sheaf $pr_1^*(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(1))$ has a section $pr_1^*(x_1)$. It is obvious that the divisor of zeros and poles of this section is the projective line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you explain your last statement a bit more? That's not clear for me why the divisor of global section $pr_1^*(x_1)$ is the projective line. What do you mean with poles and zeros of $pr_1^*(x_1)$? Sure, you can consider the global section $x_1$ as poynomial, so you can there indeed talking about "zeros and poles", but what happens with it after applying $pr_1^* $?

Comment: A line bundle is locally trivial, hence a rational section may be locally considered as a rational function, which has zeros and poles. $pr_1^*(x_1)$ has no poles, because it is a global section. It is obvious that the set of zeros of an induced section is the preimage of the set of zeros of the original section (I use the intuition described e.g. in the article "Pullback bundle" on Wikipedia).